# Uncaught ReferenceError: pk_mer is not defined

Tags: google-chrome

I am getting this error on every page in Chrome Browser.
Can anyone please tell me why this is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes when you have any extension added to chrome.

So, find the extension which is causing to above error and remove it.

It will solve your problem.

Thanks.